# Angular 14: Older IOS Compatibility

Tags: ios, angular

## Hello, I am currently having an issue with Angular 14.2.5 support for IOS safari compatibility from version 12 to latest.

[browserlistrc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XP9DV.png)

## polyfill

```
import '@angular/localize/init';
import { SDGRwindow } from '@icApp/page.checkout/\_types/SDGRwindow';
import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es6/number';
import 'core-js/es6/math';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/es6/date';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es7/array';
import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';
import 'classlist.js';
import 'core-js/es6/reflect';
import 'core-js/es7/reflect';
import 'web-animations-js';
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';

(window as unknown as SDGRwindow).ICARD_IS_IE = false;

if (!Element.prototype.matches) {
(window as unknown as SDGRwindow).ICARD_IS_IE = true;
Element.prototype.matches = (Element.prototype as any).msMatchesSelector;
}
```

Whenever I try to access the website using browserstack, I am receiving this set of issues:

[SyntaxErrors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WjDzX.png)

[Webpack-dev-server not connecting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cjOMH.png)

I tried modifying the polyfill, maybe a certain module must be added for coverage but no luck. Also tried downgrading tsconfig.json target from es2020 to es5. It works for older versions, but from ios safari 13.4 and above, it doesn't.

The goal is to cover compatibility from ios safari 12 to latest.

Note: Currently, I am using package.json>target: "es2020"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try to lower your target into es2018 on tsconfig.json

Comment: This should be a comment instead of an answer.

Comment: Thanks!!! It works like a charm!!! 

Note: I also used 
module: "es2015" and 
lib: [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]